# Custom link and name meta box in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I would like to create a metabox in the section of edit post menu. Like Tags for exemple, BUT instead of inserting tags I would like to put a link (ex. http://www.google.com) + name.

This link should go right to the end of my post content as a hyperlink with "Source: Name (hyperlinked by specified link)

Here is an example of what I am needing:

Title

This post is for example

Source: [Google](http://www.google.com)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Custom Fields in Wordpress posts to add extre information to a post, then in your theme you can just grab the values.  Here is what I use on my blog:

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id);
if(!empty($custom_fields['article_source_url'][0]) && !empty($custom_fields['article_source_title'][0])){ ?>
    <strong>Source</strong>: <a href="<?php echo($custom_fields['article_source_url'][0]); ?>"><?php echo($custom_fields['article_source_title'][0]); ?></a>
<?php }
```

Then in your wordpress post just add a Source URL and Title in the custom fields box:

[image: Custom Fields]

Comment: article_source_title and url should be entered only once in custom fields? Or everytime I make a new post? Sory for this dumb question but I'm just a begginer.

Comment: No worries!  We're all begginers at some point.  You only need to add article_source_title and URL when you want to have one in the post.  If you don't include them, they won't be printed on the HTML because we check if the post has one: `!empty($custom_fields['article_source_url'][0]) && !empty($custom_fields['article_source_title'][0]))`  This is basically asking "Does the post include both a Source Title and URL?"  If yes: we print them, if not: we move on!

Comment: So, I have created those 2 custom fields title and url and I have copied your code right before the like button in post. Saved. My site is not working, showing just a white blank page. what is wrong? [link](http://www.isay.ro) is my site. If i delete your code is working.

Comment: Your site works for me.  The code in my example assumes that you're already inside a PHP script (That's why it doesn't start with `<?php`  Make sure that you're the code inside the PHP and not as html.  If you are unsure, [read the PHP Documentation on PHP Tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Yes it works because i have deleted the code. Yes is in index.php right on single posts section, available only for post not homepage

Comment: Now is working. Every code inside has <?php & ?>, I've put this and is now working.

Comment: Tried it with a new post. Using the custom field selecting again title, write, add, selecting url, write, add. To many actions, that's why I have wanted a meta-box where to put name and url and hit add. You could help me with a meta-box?

Comment: Sorry, that's out of my abilities.  I found a [good tutorial](http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/) though.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks dude for your kind help. I will take an eye to that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP's [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to denote specific parameters for each page/post.

Then, in the template, just call them like this:

```
<?php 
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
var_dump($custom_fields);
?>
```

Note that they are arrays, so in case you have a field named `URL`, you'd need to call it like

```
echo $custom_fields['URL'][0];
```

This is done like this so you can have multiple values for the same field.

Also, in order to see the Custom Fields box, you need to go to the Screen Options (top right of the edit page) and enable them.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know how to do it, thats why I choose help from you guys. Can you put the whole code here to copy/paste it in functions.php? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you don't know? I gave you all you need. Where are you stuck now?